# Handling Facebook Like Button Information (title and image) with Links with Hashtags

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

On my website, Like buttons are generated dynamically. The URLs associated with these Like buttons are links that automatically redirect (with htaccess) to its respective hashtag url (i.e. ".com/event/200" redirects to ".com/#event/200"). The issue is that I can't seem to set the title or image. When a page loads with a hashtag, a database is queried and then the page title, meta data, and other things are changed. Facebook seems to be using the metadata that's set before the database has had time to load and the content has been changed. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem? I'd love to be able to set the title and image when the like button is loaded if there's anyway to do that. Here's my like button code:

```
<fb:like href='http://website.com/"+postname+"/"+data.id+"' send='true' layout='button_count' width='450' show_faces='true'></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The URLs associated with these Like buttons are links that automatically redirect (with htaccess) to its respective hashtag url (i.e. ".com/event/200" redirects to ".com/#event/200").

That’s your *error* right there.

Since the Hash part of an URL does not get transmitted to the server, it’s only usable client-side. So redirecting to it *server-side* is a really bad idea, since you know nothing about the client’s capabilities (f.e. if it supports JavaScript).

Don’t do server-side redirects - make them client-side instead, via JS.

This tutorial shows how to basically go about making an “AJAX-Page” crawlable: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions CBroe! I was wondering how to handle SEO too... Could you explain why server-side redirects are bad? After I'm done making my pages crawlable, I shouldn't need to redirect anything ever, but I was just wondering what's wrong with server-side redirects.

Comment: Server-side redirects aren’t wrong in general – just in this case, I’d say they are pretty useless, since you don’t know upfront if the client will be able to make something useful out of the hash part. In this particular case, I would take the URL `/event/200` and redirect that _client-side_ to `/#event/200`, if the client has all the necessary techniques required to make this work.

Comment: Or for this situation, I'd need to redirect to /#!event/200. It all works now! Thanks!